# Reusing value for multiple dates in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID            Type               Change_Date               
1              t1                2015-10-08
1              t2                2016-01-03
1              t3                2016-03-07
2              t1                2017-12-13
2              t2                2018-02-01
```

It shows if a customer has changed account type and when. However, I'd like a query that can give me the follow output

```
ID            Type               Change_Date               
1              t1                2015-10
1              t1                2015-11
1              t1                2015-12
1              t2                2016-01
1              t2                2016-02
1              t3                2016-03
1              t3                2016-04
...            ...               ...
1              t3                2018-10
```

for each `ID`. The output shows what account type the customer had for each month until the current month. My problem is filling in the "empty" months. In some cases the interval between account changes can be more than a year.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base on Presto SQL(because your origin question is about Presto/SQL)**

---

**Update in 2018-11-01: use `lead()` to simplify SQL**

---

## Prepare data

Table `mytable` same as yours

```
id  type  update_date
1   t1    2015-10-08
1   t2    2016-01-03
1   t3    2016-03-07
2   t1    2017-12-13
2   t2    2018-02-01
```

Table `t_month` is a dictionary table which has all month data from `2015-01` to `2019-12`. This kind of dictionary tables are useful.

```
ym
2015-01
2015-02
2015-03
2015-04
2015-05
2015-06
2015-07
2015-08
2015-09
...
2019-12
```

---

## Add lifespan for `mytable`

Normally, your should 'manage' your data like their lifespan. So `mytable` should like

```
id  type   start_date      end_date
1   t1     2015-10-08      2016-01-03
1   t2     2016-01-03      2016-03-07
1   t3     2016-03-07      null
2   t1     2017-12-13      2018-02-01
2   t2     2018-02-01      null
```

But in this case, you don't. So next step is 'create' one. Use [`lead()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lead) window function.

```
select 
    id,
    type, 
    date_format(update_date, '%Y-%m') as start_month,
    lead(
        date_format(update_date, '%Y-%m'), 
        1, -- next one
        date_format(current_date+interval '1' month, '%Y-%m') -- if null return next month
    ) over(partition by id order by update_date) as end_month
from mytable
```

Output

```
id  type  start_month  end_month
1   t1    2015-10     2016-01
1   t2    2016-01     2016-03
1   t3    2016-03     2018-11
2   t1    2017-12     2018-02
2   t2    2018-02     2018-11
```

---

## Cross join `id` and `month`

It's simple

```
with id_month as (
    select * from t_month 
    cross join (select distinct id from mytable)
)
select * from id_month
```

Output

```
ym      id
2015-01 1
2015-02 1
2015-03 1
...
2019-12 1
2015-01 2
2015-02 2
2015-03 2
...
2019-12 2
```

---

## Finally

Now, you can use `subquery` in `select` clause

```
select 
    id,
    type,
    ym
from (
    select
        t1.id,
        t1.ym,
        (select type from mytable2 where t1.id = id and t1.ym >= start_month and t1.ym < end_month) as type
    from id_month t1
)
where type is not null
-- order by id, ym
```

---

## Full sql

```
with mytable2 as (
    select 
        id,
        type, 
        date_format(update_date, '%Y-%m') as start_month,
        lead(
            date_format(update_date, '%Y-%m'), 
            1, -- next one
            date_format(current_date+interval '1' month, '%Y-%m') -- if null return next month
        ) over(partition by id order by update_date) as end_month
    from mytable
)
, id_month as (
    select * from t_month 
    cross join (select distinct id from mytable)
)
select 
    id,
    type,
    ym
from (
    select
        t1.id,
        t1.ym,
        (select type from mytable2 where t1.id = id and t1.ym >= start_month and t1.ym < end_month) as type
    from id_month t1
)
where type is not null
--order by id, ym
```

Output

```
id  type  ym
1   t1    2015-10
1   t1    2015-11
1   t1    2015-12
1   t2    2016-01
1   t2    2016-02
1   t3    2016-03
1   t3    2016-04
...
1   t3    2018-10
2   t1    2017-12
2   t1    2018-01
2   t2    2018-02
...
2   t2    2018-10
```

Comment: The SQL is complicated which I think it's because of the 'poor' table structure. If table struture designed well, it will simplify your questions.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you.